# Nuked Dell utility partion...can't boot

Tags: windows, windows-xp

So I made a bonehead error....I deleted the dell utility partion since it was showing up as d: using Partition Wizard.  Now the Dell will not boot.  I've tried fixmbr and fixboot from the recovery console and made the drive active via ubcd, with no change.

Any ideas?  The xp repair will not run since it doesnt see an mbr...

Answer (score 0):

Fixmbr should have installed a new MBR, not sure why it didn't, I would back up my data and reinstall XP Clean

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/